# Integration of a homogenous function over a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

$f: \mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and homogenous of degree k.
$B = \{p \in \mathbb{R^3}:|p|\leq1 \}$, the region bounded by $S^2$, the unit sphere.
In the formula,
$
\int_{B} \Delta f dx\wedge dy \wedge dz = \int_{S^2}kfdS
$

I'm guessing that $\Delta $is an identity mapping, not the Laplacian, right?

Comment: You're guessing incorrectly. $\Delta$ is in fact the Laplacian. Review Green's identities.